# HANA Express Scriptserver not running

Tags: hana

Since some days the scriptserver on my tenant DB doesn't run anymore.

```
The active status of scriptserver on host hxehost, port 30043 has been NO for 700 seconds.
The active status of scriptserver on host hxehost, port 30046 has been NO for 700 seconds.
```

I tried already to set the value <1>within daemon.ini[scriptserver] config file on SystemDB:

System --> new value = 1

Host --> new value = 1

But the scriptserver doesn't start.

[trace](https://answers.sap.com/storage/temp/29048-scriptserver-hxehost-30004-rtedump-20170406-093308.txt)

Comment: Could you execute the following SQL in your tenant database and share the output? SELECT * FROM SYS.M_SERVICES;